# Azure: System assigned identity cannot be used

Tags: azure

One of our app services has a system assigned identity:

[image: [System assigned identity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WSEj.png)]

We wanted to start using Azure keyvault and use this identity to give this app service access.
Unfortuntatly the identity cannot be found:

[image: [Identity not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MezGU.png)]

Did anybody had a similar problem before?

I tried to find the system assigned identity in other places like Azure Ad but it could not be found there either.

I tried using systen assigned identities for other app services we have and it worked for those. So the problem is only present for that specific one.

Comment: If you use system assigned identity you can also easily find it by web app name.

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results successfully as below:***

I created an **Azure App Service** and turned-on System Managed Identity:

[image]

Copy the Object ID and you will find the application in **Azure Enterprise Applications** as below:

[image]

Now, I created an Azure Key Vault and created access policy:

Search with the **`ObjectID`** of the Application as below:

[image]

***The access policy created successfully using Service Principal as below:***

[image]